# Proper way to print a shipping label - half letter sheet

Tags: windows-7, printing

I have a shipping label (half letter size) + payment slip / tracking confirmation (another half), printed from PayPal. There is no way to avoid printing of payment slip, using CanadaPost, as far as I know, so it will print the full letter page filled with text.

I thought maybe I can cut the other half with scissors, and just make sure I feed half letter sized paper, but not sure how it will impact printer and toner yield. Will it start printing where there is no paper (expecting full letter sheet) and then I end up having toner all over printer interior?

**Question:** Is there any way I can print only the first half of the page, i.e. actual shipping label and don't print the other half? I would prefer a clean / software solution, if such exists.

**What I have tried so far**

- Print from my browser, with headers disabled and minimum margins. It prints both halfs, shipping label fits on the first, other half is wasted.
- Print using system dialog, and set paper size to half sheet. Problem is that it automatically sets regular margins, and there is no way to change those from my printer dialog. End result - only half of the page prints, but it takes over a half because of the margins, so it would not fit on a label.
- Print to PDF and then use Nitro PDF reader to send to a printer. When prompted, change paper size to half sheet. End result - it prints whole page shrinked to half sheet, and transposed.

**EDIT:** shipping label looks like this (personal information blacked out):

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do, I'm a bit confused. Maybe use images to let us see what you are trying todo? :)

Comment: @GamErix: posted an image - please see my edit.

Comment: @Neolisk: Sounds like a script or utility that would crop every image to the exact same dimensions would be of use to you. Why not use something like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/)?

Comment: @Karan: if no better option exists, this one sounds interesting. I will play with it and let you know if it works. +1

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the text in the part you want to print, and then in the print dialog, select "Print: selection". This will only print the text you have chosen.

Comment: The whole label is graphics, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows' Paint application, you can easily crop, print the cropped image, and then quit Paint without saving the changes. I don't know the specifics, but I suspect the default image editors on other platforms function similarly. Does that work for what you want to do?

Comment: I thought about this. One of the problems is consistency - I need to guarantee specific/fixed crop size at all times, which is practically impossible. Otherwise some part of the label may go outside of allowed bounds, i.e. part which is peeled off. Another problem is print quality.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to cut out the half you want to be printed with pain, then copy the cropped half over into Microsoft word or OpenOffice. additionally you can set the page rotation to landscape, then edit the marigins and select the paper format. Then it will print exactly like it's showing on your screen.

Edit:

In paint you can also specify the format and marigins in where your (croped) image should be printed, it should be automaticly rescaled.

The options you can specify in Print->Page setup.
[image]

Comment: See my comment to [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/529062/101043). Aside from the problems I outlined, this approach is not cost effective.

Comment: @Neolisk see my edit? :$

Comment: It's not a problem to paste into word and print from there. Cropping itself is.

Comment: if cropping is a problem because of the image is bigger thn your window.. use the magnifier glass to make the image fit on your screen? then select the area you want to be printed and then crop ? ;o

Comment: You mean convert PDF to image, open with paint, zoom out and then crop? It solves the problem with image quality, but it's still a hassle to perform every time. And it needs a reliable PDF to image converter.

Answer (score 0):

This online tool will do it. If you rotate the PDF first, you can print only page 1 on Zebra thermal 4x6 printer

https://www.sejda.com/rotate-pdf-pages
https://www.sejda.com/split-pdf-down-the-middle